# Using String Array in HashMap, Java

Tags: java, arrays, jvm, hashmap

I have a hashmap that contains multiple string arrays. I am trying to output each element in one of the arrays  of the hashmap however I seem to always get

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
```

Here is my code,

```
import java.util.HashMap;
public class TestApp {
    private static HashMap<String, String[]> subjects;
    public TestApp() {
        HashMap<String, String[]> subjects = new HashMap<String, String[]>();
        subjects.put("calculus",new String[] {"math","logic"});
        subjects.put("chemisty",new String[] {"ions","electrons"});
        subjects.put("biology",new String[] {"life","bacteria"});
    }
    public static void main(String[] args){
        for(String s:subjects.get("biology")){
            System.out.println(s);
        }
    }


}
```

How can i stop this issue?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

1. You've redefined a new local variable `subjects` inside of `TestApp()` which is unrelated to the `private static` variable.
2. Where are you instantiating `TestApp()`?  That code is not getting run in the first place.

Either do all your code in `main` (or related static functions), or do your code in `TestApp()` and just instantiate an instance in `main`.  For example:

```
private static HashMap<String, String[]> subjects;

public TestApp() {
}

public static void main(String[] args){
    subjects = new HashMap<String, String[]>();
    subjects.put("calculus",new String[] {"math","logic"});
    subjects.put("chemisty",new String[] {"ions","electrons"});
    subjects.put("biology",new String[] {"life","bacteria"});
    for(String s:subjects.get("biology")){
        System.out.println(s);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5):

To set up the map to be available from a static method, you need to initialize it in a static block.  Building it in a constructor won't prove anything, Java does not run that constructor before calling `main`.

```
import java.util.HashMap;
public class TestApp {
    private static HashMap<String, String[]> subjects;

    static {
        subjects = new HashMap<String, String[]>();
        subjects.put("calculus",new String[] {"math","logic"});
        subjects.put("chemisty",new String[] {"ions","electrons"});
        subjects.put("biology",new String[] {"life","bacteria"});
    }

    public static void main(String[] args){
        for(String s:subjects.get("biology")){
            System.out.println(s);
        }
    }

}
```

Also as an aside since you seem to be a student, it's usually considered a good practice to program to interfaces when possible.  i.e., we would prefer to declare `private static Map<String, String[]> subjects;` over HashMap when there's no reason it needs to be a specific kind of Map

Comment: I didn't know that "static blocks" existed. That's really cool.

Answer (score 2):

You declare `subjects` twice. One as a class member which is null and one as a local variable in your constructor. Your constructor shoild start with the following line to work with the class member:

```
subjects = new HashMap<String, String[]>();
```

And you need to create a new `TestApp` instance in `main` before your loop.

Answer (score 0):

You have not created a `TestApp` object reference inside the `main` method.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    ta = new TestApp();
    for (String s : ta.subjects.get("biology")) {
        // do your thing
    }
}
```

Also, you have redeclared subjects inside the constructor. Use:

```
public TestApp() {
    subject = ... // not HashMap<String, String[]> subjects =
    // and so on as before
}
```